# Is there any issue with using aerosols on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, melacha-creative-work

I've heard from many people that you shouldn't use aerosols (such as air fresheners, disinfectants or deodorants) on shabbos, usually citing some vague reason of changing the form from liquid to gas, or some such. This always seemed rather insubstantial as the mist that issues from an aerosol can is actually just small liquid droplets.

So, is there any truth to this? Is it indeed forbidden for this, or any other, reason? Is there any truth to this concern?

Comment: Funny, I was told to use aerosol deodorant instead of roll on on shabbos. (back in camp)

Comment: Same here...But not in camp

Comment: Deodorant is different because it is being sprayed onto your body, not into the wind. Roll-on is a problem because it is "Memachaik" (smoothing) (mimareach is the toleda melacha)

Comment: I recall reading this in the 39 malachos books and being a machokis. Some saying it is a problem and some saying it would be ok for aerosol but not for spray bottles based on the idea of winnowing using wind (air) but an aerosol bottle not actualy using the wind

Comment: @CashCow Source that liquid from a roll-on is memachaik?

Comment: I was referring to roll-on deodrant that is like a solid block not a liquid.

Comment: @CashCow It's still a Melakha shEinah Tzerikha leGufah. You are trying to apply the material to the skin, not smooth out the stick.

Comment: Rubbing ointment on skin is all about the skin not the ointment. The question though is where you apply it simply for the smell, i.e. as anointing, rather than to smooth or heal the skin in some way. We don't rule Halacha here as you know but we can state what the potential issues may be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Shulchan Aruch Harav](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25073&st=&pgnum=561) writes (based on a Yerushalmi) that if one who spits into the wind, and the wind spreads it out, he violated the Shabbos prohibition of Zora (winnowing). He adds that it may be only a Rabbinic prohibition, as it is a Melacha Sheina Tzricha Legufa.

However, in [Hilchos Pesach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25074&st=&pgnum=177) he writes that in order for one to violate Zora one must do it in a way of Borer. In other words, it must be similar to classical winnowing where the wind separates the chadd from the wheat.

However, the [Ktzos Hashulchan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7727&st=&pgnum=18) writes that even according to the lenient opinion in the Shulchan Aruch Harav in Hilchos Pesach, there is still a Rabbinic prohibition to spit into the wind (or to destroy Chametz on Pesach by crumbing it and throwing it into the wind) as it appears to winnowing.

However, the [Mishna Brura](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=286) rules leniently for two reasons.

The first is a Tshuva of R' Akiva Eiger where he was asked if one is permited to throw water out of a window where the wind will scatter the droplets. R' Akiva permitted it for two reasons:

1. The Yerushalmi isn't mentioned in the early poskim and the Halacha is like the Bavli that Zora requires Borer (a separation of good from bad) and
2. Even if there is a concept of Zora where there is no Borer, it's possible that it applies only to things that grow from the ground (as winnowing is similar to threshing and gathering which are only prohibited to be done to items which grow from the ground). As R' Akiva Eiger says that spit is considered something that grows from the ground, the Yerushalmi prohibits spitting into the wind. However, water (which) isn't something which grows from the ground and would be permitted to scatter.
3. One doesn't care if the water is scattered, and according to some opinions a Psik Reisha whose result isn't needed is allowed.

The second reason is the Alfei Menashe which says that the Yerushalmi isn't prohibiting spitting into the wind because of Zora but because of carrying in a public domain. Therefore, everyone (including the Yerushalmi) would agree that Zora requires Borer.

So it appears from the Shulchan Aruch Harav that there is (at least) a Rabbinical decree against scattering objects (the Shulchan Aruch Harav includes bread in the prohibition, and the Ktzos Hashulchan includes paper).

According to the Mishna Brura, it would appear to be permitted.

However, according to [Rabbi Yosef Yitzchak Zalmanov](https://smslarav.co.il/rabbis), one would be [permitted](https://smslarav.co.il/question/5913ad0e2d2ab20001ed3b60) to apply spray deodorant on Shabbos. Presumably, it's because there's no *wind* involved in spraying deodorant.

Comment: According to Yalkut Yosef, Siman 318-319 I believe it is Mutar.

Comment: Wait, is that a typo? R'A"K says spit IS something that grows from the ground? (I can't look it up right now.)

Answer (score 3):

From what I recall, [this](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=12/17/2007) seems like a pretty accurate summary.  In short, it is debatably an issur deoraisa, but the custom is to be lenient based on the bavli.

**A longer summary:**

Winnowing is a process of throwing threshed grains into the wind to rid them of their (lighter) chaff.

Talmud Yerushalmi applies this melacha to anythig thrown to the wind to scatter. For example, the Yerushalmi would prohibit shaking your tablecloth into the air to get rid of the crumbs.

Talmud Bavli limits this melacha to a form of selection (borer, meraked and zoreh are similar, but use different vehicles).  Zoreh is the melacha of selecting through wind.  Accordingly, one would only be chayav if there was a borer-type purification process.

The application to aerosols is obvious- the Yerushalmi would say the scattering particles is a Torah prohibition, the Bavli would say there is no connection  to a melacha here since the particles are all similar.

Although the Rema ([O.C. 319:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=288)) seems to sides with the Yerushalmi, later poskim are lenient for various reasons (see Biur Halacha there).

Comment: Could you summarize it here?

Comment: @HODOFHOD Summary: It is permissible to spray aerosols on Shabbat. Yechave Daat 6:25 Menuhat Ahava 2:207 and according to this it would seem that the Mishna Berura (siman 319) would be Matir as well.

Comment: Ummm... I meant as in reasons and opinions for and against

Comment: The Rama holds (319 O"H) that it would be Asur to spit into the wind because of Zoreh. However, the Mishna Beura disagrees and says that one doesn't try to winnow the spit (see Yalkut Yosef siman 319). That it also the opinion of Hacham Ovadia Y"D 6:25

Comment: how does spitting into the wind apply to aerosol, which has no wind mechanism?

Comment: @avi Do you want me to ask R' Mansour how this is connected?

Comment: @avi I just looked up the source from Y"D and Rav Ovadia brings the Rama there.

Comment: @avi. I suspect the compressed air acts (and qualifies) as wind.

Comment: @H'Gabriel, see the Biur Halacha who expands on the permissibility.

Comment: @YDK Saw it :-)

Comment: @H'Gabriel I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: @HodofHod I think aerosols use a chemical propellant, which it seems many authorities consider different enough from wind do be ok. However, regular vacuum spray bottles *may* be an issue. In practice, it seems many are lenient about both> See here: http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=36684