# canned whipped cream on shabbas?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, technology

Can one use a pressure can of whipped cream on shabbas ?

It is funny because on the actual can it says to ask your Rabbi if one can use it or not.

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12605

Comment: Different because of a issue of nolad

Comment: (You're right, it's not a dupe). The answer is suggested by your second sentence - different rabbis have different opinions on whether this is a problem of *molid* (e.g. [lenient p'sak](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=996&article=3786) and [stringent p'sak](http://www.dinonline.org/2010/12/05/whip-cream-on-shabbos-2/)). See also [this audio shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/761831/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Ice_Cubes_and_Whipped_Cream_on_Shabbos).

Comment: which can?......

Comment: I think you ought to follow the can's advice, and CYLOR. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Rav Daniel Mann](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=996&article=3786) based on Rabbi Mordechai Willig says it is permitted.

> The most serious issue is molid, creating a new reality by changing
>   the phase of an object. The baraita (Shabbat 51b) forbids crushing ice
>   and snow. Rashi explains that it is like a melacha, in that one
>   creates something new, i.e., a liquid from a solid. Some say that,
>   similarly, one may not turn a liquid into a solid, e.g., freeze water
>   to make ice cubes (see Doveiv Meisharim I, 55). We dealt with this
>   issue in Hemdat Yamim (Miketz 5767), and cited strong grounds for
>   leniency. Orchot Shabbat (15:(45)) says that even those who forbid
>   making ice cubes could permit spraying whipped cream from a canister
>   because the only purpose of the cream in the canister is to be turned
>   into whipped cream. On the other hand, here one actively and directly,
>   with the press of the button, creates the foam, as opposed to putting
>   water in a freezer, which only provides a cold setting for the slow
>   process of freezing to begin (see Shemirat Shabbat K’hilchata
>   10:(14)). However, Rav Mordechai Willig told me another reason for
>   leniency: the change, from a thick liquid to a foam, is not enough to
>   be considered molid. While one can make the argument that it is
>   forbidden to spray whipped cream from its canister, common practice is
>   to permit it. Since we have shown the halachic basis for the practice,
>   we do not feel it is necessary to change it. (We have not dealt with
>   the issue of using the cream to write words or make likenesses of
>   specific objects.)

Answer (score 2):

I saw in the [Rivevos Ephraim chelek 8:158:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1082&pgnum=103) a few shittos on this topic asked by a bachur to the gedolim.
Rabbi Goldstein assurs it because of nolad,also in the sefer Hilchos shabbas in the kitchen pg.961 Rabbi Menashe Klein,Rabbi Moshe Stern(Be'er Moshe) and Rabbi ראטה(not sure which one) hold the same opinion.

Rav Scheinberg,Rav Fisher,Rav Dovid Feinstein held its mutar,also Rav Belsky(see lamed tet Mahlachos hilchos dosh footnote 176a for a different savarah or opinion).See it inside.

The sefer Rishumei Ahron chelek 2:pg 30:3 brings down the opinion of Rav Moshe that there is no issur of nolad by a whipped cream aerosol can.

Answer (score 1):

It says on Halachipedia.com

> It is forbidden to use whipped topping or whipped cream from a can on
>   Shabbat. [18]

Halachipedia's sources: ↑ 39 Melachos (vol 2, pg 371), Halachically Speaking (vol 4, Issue 16, pg 5) quoting Rav Yisrael Belsky