# Can a Shabbat guest benefit from food that the host prepares if his custom is to forbid that preparation?

Tags: melacha-creative-work

I see that there is a debate whether a person can use canned whipped cream on Shabbat. Refer to [This discussion.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28520/canned-whipped-cream-on-shabbas) Suppose that I forbid using canned whipped cream. I am a guest a someone's home and my host feels it's permissible. They serve a desert using the canned whipped cream. Can I eat it, or would I be benefiting from a Jew's *melacha* as I believe that using the whipped cream is a melacha?