# Is one allowed to spray cologne on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, smell, personal-hygiene

Is one allowed to spray cologne on shabbos? Any rules against doing this?

As always, please cite your sources

Comment: assuming an atomizer is like an aerosol in dispersal, related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/is-there-any-issue-with-using-aerosols-on-shabbos and assuming tat a spray is a spray and the issue isn't pikuach nefesh, it still seems ok http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5755/korach.html

Comment: but for a direct discussion https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=6/4/2010

Comment: On clothing is problematic

Comment: First, is a man allowed to spray cologne at all?

Comment: Why do you think this may be prohibited that you ask? Please [edit] in your motivation to improve this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary source is the in Gemara in Bietza 23a which discusses Molid Re'ech - creating a smell on an object.

Rashi (D'Ka Molid) there explains that it's a Rabbinic prohibition; it's similar to doing work.

This does not apply to food items, according to most Poskim - and according to how we Pasken.

The earlier Poskim argue if this applies to the body. For example, the Taz (511:8) disallowed it. However the Mishna Berura allows it. (This can be inferred from 327:1 that a healthy person can use Rose Water.)

There's some major discussion if it's allowed even if it will inevitably cause one's clothes to also smell good.

All this - with lots of sources -  and more you can find on **page 330 of Vol 3 in Sefer Orchot Shabbat** (In Hebrew, by Rabbis Gelber and Rubin, Jerusalem 2009 ).

In short: If you spray it onto your body - but not enough that your clothes will smell of it - then everybody allows it.

Comment: Perfect. Can you add a source for the Mishna Berura?

Comment: @Bochur613 - done. Inline.