# using static guard on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, electricity

Would there be any reason why one would not be able to apply static guard to clothing on Shabbos? Would it make any difference if the clothing is currently being worn or not?

Two points:

1- I believe you are not allowed to spray perfume on clothing on Shabbos (Why, I can't recall at the moment). Static guard is scented but the smell is not why one would apply it. So does that prohibition come into play?

2- I was wondering if any of you would be able to think of any other melachos that would come into play here.

Thanking everyone in advance,

Gitty

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33750

Comment: That answers the question of why it would be an issue to spray perfume on clothing :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I located [this](http://www.puretorah.com/resources/Melachot%20Part%205.pdf) which has a summary of some Do's / Dont's of some of the 39 *Melachot* It says:

> Whitening/Scouring What: Cleansing in any manor of absorbent materials with absorbed dirt or the bleaching of such materials.
>
> Do: Wash dishes, cups, etc. Use paper napkins to clean up spills Dry
>   dishes with a cloth Hang up a suit jacket Hang up a rain coat Dry ones
>   hands on a towel ( (דרך לכלוך **Spray static guard on a clingy dress**
>   Walk around in the rain
>
> Don't: Wash, soak or scrub dirty materials Scrub or rub hard a
>   material even dry ( (שפשוף Soak dirty towels ( (שרייה Ring out water
>   from a white towel ( (סחיטה Put water on a stain on clothes or carpet
>   Polish silver Have a water balloon fight Use towels to soak up spills
>   Put a wet garment near a radiator to dry off Hang up clothes to dry
>   that are typically washed (ie. not dry cleaned)

You have a separate question regarding spraying, which is addressed [here](http://www.sephardichalacha.org/2014/11/spraying-air-fresheners-on-shabbat.html):

> Air fresheners and perfumes that are sprayed are not considered to be
>   Zoreh, and therefore it is permissable use them on Shabbat. However,
>   one may not spray perfume onto clothing or fabric. Directly onto skin
>   is okay.

From what I read about static guard, I gather that they do make them in sheets as opposed to a spray. That may avoid any melachot, that way. Also, you may want to check with a Rav. Perhaps since the scent is secondary and not the intent of using the static guard, it may be permissible. The above quote seems to imply specifically to perfumes on dresses, i.e. - products that are specifically used for scents.

Comment: Very, very interesting. I can't believe you found a source which addresses static guard directly. Do you know who put it together? Both sources you referenced seem to be according to Sephardic Poskim. I wonder if there would be any difference by Ashkenazim?

Comment: @Gitty - I wish that the 1st link gave me some idea of who is responsible for the web site, but I couldn't find anything. The 2nd source, I think is a bit more obvious. At any rate, there are a number of general opinions saying that aerosol sprays are not zoreh. There's a related M.Y. question about spraying related to the use of spray whipped cream on Shabbat. That's how I know about that.