# Hairspray on Shabbos Allowed?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, boneh-soter

Is one allowed to use hairspray on shabbos? Let's say a braid was made before shabbos and one wants to spray the braid on shabbos to prevent it from getting messy.

Comment: related: [Is there any issue with using aerosols on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12605/11501)

Comment: In addition to mbloch's answer, there is a debate as to whether one can use any type of spray as it might be considered like "winnowing". This isn't specific to hairspray but I've seen this warning on kosher canned whipped cream. I'll see if I can find a better article on this, and post as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

For any practical application, you should ask your rav as this is an issue where *poskim* (halachic decisors) differ. R Eliezer Melamed [forbids it](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-14-03/)

> One may not use hair spray or oil to keep one’s hair in place, because
>   this is similar to Boneh (Rivash as cited in BHL 303:27 s.v. “laĥof”).

Matzav.com brings a more nuanced perspective though

> The use of hairspray which will stiffen the hair and form a structure may
>   involve the Melocho of Boneh (building). If one sprays the hair first
>   and then styles and shapes it; this would be prohibited on Shabbos
>   because it is similar to Boneh.
>
> However, some poskim permit the use of
>   hairspray if one is careful to first style and shape the hair, and
>   then only afterwards add the hairspray. When done in this manner the
>   loose hair is shaped at the time of styling, and does not resemble
>   Boneh because the hair is loose. The subsequent spraying merely acts
>   to retain a pre-existing shape. Once the hair has been sprayed it can
>   no longer be shaped, styled, or touched.
>
> Shulchan Aruch w/Mishnah Brurah 302, Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchasa
>   14:50:131, Kitzur Hilchos Shabbos re:Gozez:5:16, Biur Halacha 303:27,
>   Hilchos Shabbos R’ Shimon Eider, Minchas Yitzchok 6:26, Sefer 39
>   Melochos

[Halachafortoday](https://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/q-page-14.html) (651) brings a similar approach from the Mishna Brura

> If you style [the hair] first and then afterwards spray a little hairspray, it
>   is permitted according to many Poskim, as the spray is then only 
>   maintaining the hair’s shape. Spraying first, however, and then
>   styling it is prohibited. (See [Mishna Brura] Biur Halacha 303:27 Dibur
>   Hamaschil Lachuf)

So please [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) - hoping the above sources will help him come to the right decision.