# Is pepper spray muktzah?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

Is it permitted to carry pepper spray for self-protection on Shabbos or Yom Tov mitzad muktzah?

[Is there any issue with using aerosols on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12605/6886) discusses a machlokes of using sprays on Shabbos, however, according to the stringent opinions, would pepper spray be muktzah being that it's carried around for self defense?

I don't think this is a clear cut case of pikuach nefesh, as there's not necessarily any tangible threat, it's just a precaution.

Comment: Or a knife, or a gun... Why do you ask about pepper spray specifically?

Comment: @DonielF a knife can be used for food or many other things that are definitely muttar, and it definitely doesn't have any issue with zoreh. A gun would be ossur except in a case of pikuach nefesh, as it makes a spark and causes bleeding, among other issues, while pepper spray might be mutar in a case of defending property, unless there's a problem of zoreh.

Comment: A knife is a kli shemelachto l’heter. That isn’t a blanket allowance to carry it anywhere. While I don’t have sources, i know lots of people who carry guns on Shabbos. You make a good point with zoreh - you should edit it into your question.

Comment: @DonielF good point. Then maybe a knife is more of an issue, as it'll cause blood in a defense situation. The main reason why I mentioned pepper spray is because that's what I'm interested to know. I don't have a gun and I don't carry knives.

Comment: pepper spray is inherently food https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNYobXLCUhY

Comment: If the pepper spray is being carried for self-defense I don't see why it'd be different than carrying a gun which is also permissible (Shmirat Shabbat KeHilchita 8:28)

Comment: @Doniel Some (Tosafot?) hold that cutlery has the same status as food and can be carried in all circumstances