# Halachic explanation of King David closeness with Avishag

Tags: king-david, negia, melachim-kings-book-of

Shulhan Aruch [Even HaEzer 21 and 22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.21.1?lang=bi) records the Halacha against men and women touching each other (especially Derech Hiba; whether it is Deorayta or Derabanan is a Mahloket Rishonim between Rambam and Ramban).

So my question is, how did Dawid Hamelech take a woman ([Melachim 1:1-5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a01.htm)) to comfort him and keep him warm when he wasn't married to her (as far as I know)?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't derech chiba?

Comment: @DoubleAA 1) even if it isn't it is still Asur. 2) I think it clearly was.

Comment: @Vram well that kinda is Soter the idea of the Maan DaAmar that the shaking one's hand in a business setting is "Yehareg VeAl Yaavor."

Comment: @Vram http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11626/1035

Comment: If she was a nurse it's quite a different story.

Comment: Probably wasn't assur back then. Derabannan from later.

Comment: @Hacham then you should be asking that Maan DaAmar, no?

Comment: Even if not S"N, is there no leeway for the elderly in hospice care?

Comment: @SethJ that seems to be a Kashe on this-http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11625/se-challenge-halachot-in-which-rulings-range-from-permissible-to-torah-violatio/11626#11626

Comment: Yes and no. I think circumstances matter.

Comment: @ALK see my comment to my answer, that even if it was derabanan, it was decreed during the time of King David, before the story with Avishag: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13956/603

Comment: @HachamGabriel I'm going out on a limb here, but if she was a penuya tehorah then why is there an issur negia?

Comment: @DoubleAA the Isur of Negiya is separate then that of Nida IIRC.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Yes but Negia is only assur with an erva. A penuya tehora is not an erva.

Comment: @DoubleAA oh, then IDK why you said "going out on a limb" because it sounds pretty valid.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I don't have an explicit source and I'm  imagining it will be a little controversial to propose that Avishag only came to David the three weeks per month that she was tehorah. If you think it's ok then I'll post. (Even unmarried women back then stayed mostly tehorot because of kodshim and the like.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I found the Chida [quotes](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_David,_Genesis,_Chayei_Sara.8.2) the Paneach Raza that he was בא עליה שלא כדרכה

Comment: Why couldn't she be a Pilegesh?

Answer (score 11):

The answer lies in the first verse of the same verses in 1 Kings quoted above.

> "Now King David was old and stricken in years; and they covered him with clothes, but he could get no heat."  (1 Kings 1:1)

David was an frail man at this point.  He couldn't touch a woman "affectionately" (b'derech chiba) if he tried!

The fourth verse explicitly tells us that there was no romantic encounter between David and his live-in nurse.

> "And the damsel was very fair; and she became a companion unto the king, and ministered to him; **but the king knew her not.**"  (1 Kings 1:4)

The law of nagia is the same today.  No one thinks twice about a young woman, working in a nursing home, tending to an old, observant Jewish man.  Yes, they touch.  She might even give him a sponge bath, and see his private areas; but the vast majority of old men who can no longer bathe themselves, are also incapable of any intimate relations, forbidden or permitted.

Therefore, one cannot bring a proof from these verses that the laws of nagia were different then than they are now.

Comment: What about Pilegeshim? How could they exist without kiddushin and without breaking negiah??

Comment: +1. Do you have a source for the reason you give for their lack of sexual intimacy? (I believe it: I seem to recall some _m'far'shim_ mention it. But do you have a citation?)

Comment: The Talmud (Sanhedrin 22A) tells us that David did not have relations for religious reasons, not because of lack of ability. The Talmud there says that he had relations with BatSheva 13 times, to show that he could.

Comment: @ALK: Pilagshim are discussed in detail on this webpage, http://vbm-torah.org/archive/kiddushin/01kiddushin.htm . from there: "On the other hand, Rambam writes that a halakhic kinyan, a legally recognized acquisition, is necessary to acquire a pilegesh, just as one is required to actualize marriage. Furthermore, Rambam compares pilegesh to the case of yi'ud (the process in which a master takes his maid-servant as a wife), which is a clearly defined halakhic framework....

Comment: ....The conclusion to be reached is simple. Pilegesh is an independent halakhic institution. Although it is not a form of marriage, it is, nonetheless, a recognized legal framework. Therefore, even though no kiddushin is involved in the case of pilegesh, some form of legal acquisition is required." @ALK

Comment: You guys inspired me to ask a question on pilegshim.  Check it out, and please answer and comment there. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13984/1095

Comment: **Chas Vesholom** to even say he couldn't. The Gemoro (Sanhedrin 22a) relates that Avishag begged David to have relations with her. He refused. She said to him that the reason he refused is because he was too old for it and did not have the strength. David sent for Batsheva his wife to come in, and in front of Avishag had relations with BatSheba 13 times in a row to show to Avishag that it was not from lack of strength that he refrained from having relations with her. Rather he refrained for Halachic mixed will moral reasons.

Comment: @yehuda Why is it **Chas Vesholom** to realize that that story is probably not meant to be history?

Comment: @DoubleAA its quite simply against the Gemoro. `He couldn't touch a woman "affectionately" (b'derech chiba) if he tried!` The Gemoro says that isnt the case. In my book of rules, contradicting Chazal deserves a Chas Vesholom. You're welcome to have a different set of rules for yourself.

Comment: @ALK the Radvaz [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_4.1296.2) she wasn't a pilegesh

Answer (score 11):

Not a complete answer, but here's what the Talmud [(Sanhedrin 22A)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=22&format=pdf) says (Rashi brought in נrackets):

> אמר רב שמן בר אבא בוא וראה כמה קשין גירושין שהרי דוד המלך התירו לו לייחד *[עם אבישג ואע"פ שנאסר ייחוד של פנויה]* ולא התירו לו לגרש [אחת מי"ח וישאנה]‏
>
> R' Shaman bar Aba said: Come and See how harsh divorce is. They gave permission to King David to be alone [with Avishag, even though  it was forbidden to be alone with an unmarried woman], but did not let him divorce [one of his 18 wives to marry her].

According to this, he had dispensation from "They" (which I'm assuming are the Rabbis of that time). It doesn't say why they gave this dispensation, but I'm guessing it was for health reasons.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the Talmud (Avodah Zarah 36B) says that Yichud with an unmarried Israelite woman was prohibited in the time of King David (after the incident with Amnon and Tamar). Perhaps that is why the Talmud says "They". Perhaps it means They who forbade it, made an exception for King David. - http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=36b&format=pdf

Comment: I find my typo in the word _brackets_ to be quite funny in fact considering the [biblical brackets](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0410.htm).

Answer (score 5):

I once heard a fascinating answer in the name of Rav Shimon Schwab: The Gemara in Shabbat (86) says that through battling one's yetzer hara, one becomes warmed up. David, however, says R' Schwab, had no Yetzer Hara ("velibi challal bekirbi") so he became cold since there was nothing to battle. Thus, the only way to re-warm him would be to arouse his yetzer hara again. Therefore, they brought a woman to stand in his room (which was allowed since Yichud was waived for David), but not to touch him (since, according to R' Schwab, Negiah would surely not be waived). The battle of seeing the woman in his room and making rationalizations, etc. would be the inner struggle which would help heat him up.

Rav Schwab adds that even though the Pasuk says "She will lie in your bosom," this was just the advice of the doctors to David, and David did not necessarily follow this advice.

Comment: So he had no free will?

Comment: I don't see how else to interpret R' Schwab. But again, I didn't see it inside; I just heard this answer in a Navi class once, so I could be missing some facts or important details.