# Retroactive Get

Tags: halacha, marriage, divorce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would a baalat teshuva need a get from each previous sexual relationship?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16102/would-a-baalat-teshuva-need-a-get-from-each-previous-sexual-relationship)

Suppose:

Man A seduces a virgin Woman X. 
Man B informally lies with Woman X.
Man A and Woman X informally break up.
Man B and Woman X informally break up.
Man C informally lies with Woman X.
Man C formally marries Woman X.

Should Man A gives Woman X a Get?
Might the Get be dated retroactively?
If Man A give Woman X a retroactive Get does this impact Man B?
What other obligations rest on Men A, B, C?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16102/759