# Ceremony to take a woman as a concubine (pilegesh)?

Tags: halacha, marriage

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13984/1095) sparked a lively discussion and debate on this rather sensitive issue.

One piece of the original question was:

> - What ceremony / ritual must be performed (if any) to formally designate a woman as a specific man's pilegesh?
> - What ceremony / ritual must be performed (if any) if/when the couple wants to dissolve the pilegesh relationship?

No one ever provided an answer.  I am looking for one of two things:

- Evidence that a specific ritual is used to acquire a pilegesh
- Evidence that no specific ritual is required to acquire a pilegesh

Also, if the ritual includes a written document, what is written into this document?

(There seemed to be general agreement [over here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13984/1095) that a pilegesh does not receive a ketubah).

Comment: To be clear - I don't intend to rehash the arguments from the original question.  The propriety of pilegesh in modern times is not part of this question.  I simply want to know the details of how a man acquired a pilegesh back when such an arrangement did occur.

Comment: This topic has appeared and reappeared on many an electronic Jewish forum in the last 20 years. Every time it sparks a lively debate.

Answer (score 6):

Rambam ([Hil. Melachim 4:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14930)) states that a pilegesh (which, in his view, is permissible only to a king) enters into this status "without kesubah and without kiddushin; with *yichud* alone he acquires her and she becomes permitted to him."

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may just be: "we don't know." It's too abstract.

I think it would be absolved, according to Rabbi Emden, with a normal-looking Get; and entered -- well I'm not sure in what capacity you specify "this is quasi-marriage" instead of "this is real marriage" in the ceremony. I don't know what his language is on this. (I heard a shiur about his essay, but haven't seen it myself.)

Comment: I agree that a get seems like the correct way to dissolve a pilegesh relationship.  Since Rav Emden seriously considered allowing pilegesh l'maaseh, not that long ago, it would be reasonable to assume that he had something in mind for a man and woman to do, in order to enter the pilegesh relationship.  Could it be as simple as chupah and kiddushin, without a ketubah?