# Are Pilgashim used as "place holders" in a man's life?

Tags: women, marriage, sexuality

Is it normal for a Jewish man to have a *pilegesh* to take care of physical needs when he is not yet married?

By "*pilegesh*" I mean a woman who is temporarily monogamous with him for the purpose of sex, but has no rights as a wife, no *ketubah*, but maintains her *taharah* through use of a *miqweh* (in accordance with the relevant *halakhah*).

Comment: are you assuming it is normal for anyone even to have a pilegesh?

Comment: No, it is not normal at all.

Comment: To add to Yishai's point, if anyone tried selling you the idea that is normal, be very wary of them.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13984

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Consider registering your account to unlock more features of the site. Consider also taking the following short [tour of the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Hope you stick around the site. BTW to send messages to other users preface their usernames with an @ in the message. E.g. @Elizabeth.

Comment: A point of clarification: this site generally deals with Orthodox Judaism in particular and most of the users are Orthodox and reflect Orthodox experiences (of course everyone is welcome to the site). The answers will thus generally reflect Orthodox norms. If you happen to be wondering about a non-Orthodox Jew's behavior, this should be kept in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

`Is it normal for a Jewish man to have a pilegesh to take care of physical needs when he is not yet married?`

It's unheard of nowadays. Having lived in 4 continents and dozens of communities, I have never heard of such a thing.

As per the answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13984/501) there were periods of time when it came up for discussion. Nowadays such a couple would be shunned in most (if not all) religious communities.