# Why did David Hamelech need Abishag to keep him warm, couldn't one of his wives keep him warm?

Tags: tanach

Also isn't it a sin to be with a women who one is not married to?

Comment: Also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/halachic-explanation-of-king-david-closeness-with-avishag

Comment: I don't remember who said this, but I heard that David had almost completely conquered his Yetzer Hara and therefore was going to die (because there is no purpose in life if one isn't fighting his Yetzer Hara). Avishag was specifically brought in order to arouse his Yetzer Hara so that he wouldn't die.

Comment: @Esther: this might be what you were looking for: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25790/27180