# Are there differences in halacha between different scholars?

Tags: halacha

Are there any differences between the scholars what can be considered a difference between permitted and forbidden?

For example: is there anything one scholar considers forbidden that another considered permitted?

Specifying: Are there any halacha from Sinai that is currently known to have juristic differences? Not minhaj, which relates to custom and practice, but mitzvah from Sinai

Comment: Yes this happens all the time. At the moment this is too open a question, if you could refine it so it has more clarity or focuses on a more specific area it will like get better traction

Comment: The Talmud is absolutely full of such differences. And there are still plenty of them today. Take shellac, which is used as a coating on some candies. Two opinions in the Talmud (around the year 200), two opinions in Shulchan Aruch (a code of law from the 1500s) ... and as of today, some rabbis will allow it, and others don't.

Comment: Ah! That's an example I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11625/759