# Is it Bishul Akum if a gentile boils non potable water?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, water, bishul-akum

If a gentile boils non potable water (water that can't be consumed without being boiled), does such water have a status of Bishul Akum? Is water fit to be served by a King's table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general there is no prohibition of *bishul akum* with water since its form and taste do not change through cooking. Star-K for instance [writes](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1182/food-fit-for-a-king-reviewing-the-laws-of-bishul-akum-bishul-yisroel/)

> Foods whose form and taste do not change through cooking. This applies
>   even to food that would normally not be eaten without cooking (e.g.
>   pasteurized milk or distilled water).

However, if all people would cook the non-potable water you discuss, its *din* might be stricter. R Moishe Dovid Lebovits [writes](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol14Issue6.pdf) (p. 19)

> In Eretz Yisrael many people do not drink the water without cooking it
>   first. If a non-Jew cooked the water one may still drink it since most
>   people drink it without cooking it first. **In other areas where all
>   people cook the water first the din may change, if it is cooked for
>   taste.**

However Tosfot ([Avoda Zara 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.31b.7?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Avodah_Zarah.31b.7&lang2=bi)) argue that beer is not subject to *bishul akum* because it is not proper to serve it to a king. **One could argue that boiled non-potable water is in the same category and that kings drink mineral water (see [here](https://www.yutorah.org/_cdn/_shiurim/Bishul%20Akum%20Part%20I.html)).**

I discussed the above with R Binyamin Tabady who concurred based on the last argument.